# why does the contents of bootstrap well goes to the middle of the well

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap class= well-large, inside i have a table.

i don't know why but the table goes to the middle center of the well.

what i actually want is that the table will be at the top of the well as i assume it should noramlly be.

this is my code:

```
<div collapse="!isCollapsedDebts">
                   <div class="well well-huge">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                      <tr>
                        <th>..</th>
                        <th>..</th>
                        <th>..</th>
                        <th>..</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr ng-repeat="debt in user.debts">
                        <td>{{formatDate(debt.date)}}</td>
                        <td>{{debt.hour}}</td>
                        <td>{{debt.courtId}}</td>
                        <td>{{paymentText(debt.payment)}}
                          <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-info btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#/debts"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
                                <a ng-click="changePayment(user, debt, choice)">{{choice}}</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

i have changed well-large to well-hude which i added in the bootstrap css.
this makes my problem even worser.
i have changed the padding to 200 from 24.

```
.well-huge {
  padding: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
}
```

i am not that strong in css and styles so i suppose there is a quick fix for the table to be at the top of the well and not in the center page of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells

Wells are supposed to appear inset. I'm not sure why you're using a well if you don't want your table to styled like that. Since it isn't clear what you want, I'm assuming the fix is:

```
.well-huge {
 padding-top: 0px;
}
```